# How can I get this regex to work on multi lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the regex `(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))` to match all content that's between a `{` & `}` whether on a single line or multi line.

This works on single line, but not multi line. How can multi line be done?
I've tried `(?<=\()(.\r\n)(?=\))` `(?<=\()(\s\S)(?=\))`

```
// Works on this
.a .ikd .Pf { -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px; background-size: 307px 472px; width: 100px; height: 125px;}

// Does not work on this    
.a. ikd .rbSa {
    -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px;
    background-size: 307px 472px;
    width: 58px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U1Z8DA/1)

Comment: What's wrong with `{(.*?)}` with the `s` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

\{(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]).+$)*

Take a look here: https://regex101.com/r/TorSFW/1/

Comment: Works fine, but includes the curly braces in the match.

Comment: Sorry! This is easier: \{((.*[\r\n])*)\} and get group 1

Answer (score 0):

How about `{(.*?)}` with the 'gms' flags?

https://regex101.com/r/DKSoUQ/1/

This will not include the curly braces, as demonstrated here:

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOT
// Works on this
.a .ikd .Pf { -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px; background-size: 307px 472px; width: 100px; height: 125px;}

// Does not work on this    
.a. ikd .rbSa {
    -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px;
    background-size: 307px 472px;
    width: 58px;
    height: 75px;
}
EOT;

preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/s', $input, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(97) " -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px; background-size: 307px 472px; width: 100px; height: 125px;"
  [1]=>
  string(112) "
    -webkit-background-size: 307px 472px;
    background-size: 307px 472px;
    width: 58px;
    height: 75px;
"
}
*/
```

Comment: Nothing wrong, but this will include the curly braces too.

Comment: No it won't, see my updated answer.